# How to replace multiple values in a pandas data frame using a custom function and .apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, apply

I have multiple columns with the same multiple ordinal values. I'm trying to create a function that I can use with .apply to the whole data frame.

```
def convert(value):
    if value == 'Ex':
        return value.replace('Ex', 5)
    elif value == 'Gd':
        return value.replace('Gd', 4)
    elif value == 'TA':
        return value.replace('TA', 3)
    elif value == 'Fa':
        return value.replace('Fa', 2)
    elif value == 'Po':
        return value.replace('Po', 1)
    elif value == 'NA':
        return value.replace('NA', 0)
    else:
        pass
```

I'm receiving a ValueError when I try to run my function as

`df.apply(convert, axis=0)`

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index id')
```

Does anyone know the most efficient and/or Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You need to loop all the columns if you have multiple

Comment: You should use [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with a `dict` of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `df.replace()` and pass a dictionary mapping, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

mapping = {'Ex': 5, 'Gd': 4, 'TA': 3, 'Fa': 2, 'Po': 1, 'NA': 0}

df = pd.DataFrame({'letters': ['Ex','TA','Ex','Fa','Po','TA','TA','Ex','NA','TA']})

df.replace(mapping)
```

For example, this yields:

```
   letters
0        5
1        3
2        5
3        2
4        1
5        3
6        3
7        5
8        0
9        3
```